# Сравнить числа в массиве и вывести число при совпадении С#

Tags: c#, массивы

Всем привет! Никак не могу справиться с 3 частью задачи, хотя возможно это из-за ошибок в первых двух частях :/

1 часть: Создать массив с пространством для десяти позиций, в котором хранятся целые числа.

2 часть: Теперь вы должны заполнить массив числами. Это должно быть сделано с помощью цикла for и с возможностью для  пользователя вводить эти значения.

3 часть: Объявите переменную с целым числом. Вывести все значения из вектора с помощью цикла. Если какое-либо число в векторе равно целому числу в новой переменной, это следует отметить.

Мой код на данный момент:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] tal = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 

        for (int i = 0; i < tal.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите целое число от 1 до 10: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine(); 
            int element = Convert.ToInt32(str);


            foreach (object me in tal)
                Console.WriteLine(me);
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы выполнить это условие "Если какое-либо число в векторе равно целому числу в новой переменной, это следует отметить"? Заранее спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 часть: Создать массив с пространством для десяти позиций, в котором
> хранятся целые числа.

Это сделано, хотя и не совсем корректно.
Правильнее:

```
int[] tal = new int[10]
```

Это ограничит массив десятью неинициализированными ячейками. Заполнение их цифрами заранее  - потенциальная ошибка, ведь в п.1 нет пункта заполнить их АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ.

> 2 часть: Теперь вы должны заполнить массив числами. Это должно быть
> сделано с помощью цикла for и с возможностью для пользователя вводить
> эти значения.

А вот тут правильным является только кусок цикла перебора массива, запроса ввода строки и конвертации строки в цифру. Дальше все не то.
Добавление ввода десяти цифр **пользователем** в массив, что требуется в п.2 задачи отсутствует напрочь.
Это делается через:

```
tal[i] = element;
```

> 3 часть: Объявите переменную с целым числом. Вывести все значения из
> вектора с помощью цикла. Если какое-либо число в векторе равно целому
> числу в новой переменной, это следует отметить.

Тут надо **объявить и инициализировать одну переменную** с любым числом (не сделано). Например:

```
int example = 32;
```

и затем в **ОТДЕЛЬНОМ** цикле, а не внутри существующего цикла ввода цифр, как у Вас, проверить наличие значения этой переменной в введенном массиве
Для этого блок кода (ниже) из примера надо вынести из цикла наружу **ПОСЛЕ** объявления переменной:

```
 foreach (object me in tal)
                Console.WriteLine(me);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Заменить в нем object на int (нам же не нужна лишняя упаковка\распаковка)
и добавить в него условие сравнения

```
if(me == example )
{
    Console.WriteLine(me);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

В дальнейшем рекомендую очень тщательно читать задачу. Обычно в ней важно каждое слово, и все из них сами по себе формируют алгоритм. Удачи!

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, все получилось :)

Comment: @JuliaKudriashova чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелегую галочку слева от него.